# Automating a macro with an IF condition

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Is there a way to use an IF condition to copy and paste certain cells into another sheet tab in Google Sheets?

I was thinking about running a macro, but not sure if I can run a macro with an IF condition.

If not on its own, is there an extension that might do this?

Comment: Welcome to Web Apps Stack Exchange! [Take the tour here.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) It would help immensely if you could share a copy of your spreadsheet containing dummy data and what you want the output to look like. In your face, a filter function could do that trick, though we'll have to see how your data is structured first.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You've asked a VERY broad question that almost invites a yes/no answer. Perhaps the following explanation will assist...

A macro is a type of `Apps Script`.

- The advantage of a macro is that the user doesn't have to know Apps Script syntax.
- The disadvantage of a macro is that it basically records keyboard input, and there's no simple way to inject logic into the macro.

Macros (and Apps Scripts generally) do NOT support "native" functions (such as `IF()`, `SUM()`, `VLOOKUP()`, and so on).

But an Apps Script, which is a sub-set of JavaScript, does have an [IF statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else). In fact, almost every "native" function can be created in one form or another in an Apps Script. Actually, there are usually several alternatives to achieve a given outcome.

In short, you need to start developing Apps Scripts.

- There is NO "extension" for this.
- BUT, Google is your friend and you'll find many precedents for the kind of scenario  that you've described. Of course, once you have a specific question, you can raise a new question here.

The web is awash with scripting resources though Goggle has some very good tools, You might start with the [Overview](https://www.google.com/script/start/) and the [Guide to Automating Tasks with Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples). There's more information in [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), [Triggers and Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers?hl=en) and the [Mozilla JavaScript Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript).